# Double strsplit

Tags: r

I have a situation like this:
df

```
List           Count 
R472_21:345     1   
R47_2:90        1   
R844_21:98      2   
R845_54:123     2   
R975_12:1       2
```

I would like to split the elements of the column "List" in the following way:

```
R472 21 345      
R47  2  90      
..........
```

I tried this code to split according to `:` but I'm not able to split according `_` at the same time.

```
test <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$List), "\\:"))
```

Any suggestion about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a | for OR in your pattern to split on. So you are splitting on "_" or ":".

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="List           Count 
  R472_21:345     1   
  R47_2:90        1   
  R844_21:98      2   
  R845_54:123     2   
  R975_12:1       2   ")

strsplit(as.character(df$List), "_|:")
```

Result:

```
[[1]]
[1] "R472" "21"   "345" 

[[2]]
[1] "R47" "2"   "90" 

[[3]]
[1] "R844" "21"   "98"  

[[4]]
[1] "R845" "54"   "123" 

[[5]]
[1] "R975" "12"   "1"
```

Comment: escaping the underscore isn't necessary.

Comment: yea I tend to do it for good measure with symbols. I'll remove.

Comment: hi tcash21, thanks a lot for your suggestion! i t works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Use `"_|:"` for your pattern instead instead of `"\:"`. Your call to `unlist` will concatenate everything, though. You probably don't want this.

Comment: Hi mplourde! Thanks a lot. In fact I made a mistake because I don't wont that!